# Add combobox to datagridview C# Winforms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I want to add combobox column to datagridview.
I use this code to bind data from my access database.

```
Class1.Connection.Open();
oleCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tbAuditDetails.AuditNo, tbAuditQuestions.AutoSubcontent, tbAuditQuestions.AutoID, tbAuditQuestions.Questions, tbScore.Description, tbAuditDetails.QuestionID, tbAuditQuestions.QuestAutoID, tbAuditDetails.ScoreID, tbScore.Score, tbAuditQuestions.SubContentID, tbAuditDetails.ProfileID FROM ((tbAuditDetails INNER JOIN tbAuditQuestions ON tbAuditDetails.QuestionID = tbAuditQuestions.QuestionID) INNER JOIN tbScore ON tbAuditDetails.ScoreID = tbScore.ScoreID) WHERE (([tbAuditDetails.AuditNo] = " + Class1.detailsauditno + ") AND ([tbAuditQuestions.AutoSubcontent] = '" + newautosubcontentid + "') AND ([tbAuditDetails.ProfileID] = " + proid + ")) ORDER BY [tbAuditQuestions.QuestAutoID], [tbAuditDetails.QuestionID]", Class1.Connection);
oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleCommand);
oleBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleAdapter);

oleDs = new DataSet();
oleAdapter.Fill(oleDs, "tbAuditDetails");
oleTable = oleDs.Tables["tbAuditDetails"];

Class1.Connection.Close();

dataGridView1.DataSource = oleDs.Tables["tbAuditDetails"];
```

I want change one column into combobox, so i can choose the value. This combobox value come from another table, it called "tbscore" (id, description).

> tbScore.Description

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void AddComboboxColumn()
{
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColComboBox );
 ColComboBox.DataPropertyName = "ScoreID";
 ColComboBox.HeaderText = "Category";
 ColComboBox.ValueType = typeof(string);
 ColComboBox.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
 ColComboBox.DisplayIndex = 2;
 ColComboBox.Width = 150;
 ColComboBox.DataSource = oleDs ;
 ColComboBox.DisplayMember = "description";
 ColComboBox.ValueMember = "ScoreID";
 ColComboBox.Name = "ScoreID";
 ColComboBox.DataPropertyName = "ScoreID";
}
```

You can call this function after your code