# How to have a listbox in dataGridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I want to have listbox in specific column cells in a dataGridview

**why I'm doing that ?**

because I have a xml structure which some of it's parameters have multiple values

and why I don't use multi line text for each cell instead ?
because each value has an other related value which is hidden from user and I want to use listbox valueMeber for that

**What I have tried:**

Multiline text in Gridview:

[winforms - C#: multiline text in DataGridView control - Stack Overflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell?forum=winformsdesigner)

trying to have a listbox in the following solution
but speaking frankly , I couldn't do that

[Multiple controls in a single DataGridView cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell?forum=winformsdesigner)

Comment: No way to use Devexpress? It will be much simpler.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - What you want sounds like a ComboBoxCell, doesn't it?

Comment: @PawełSwajdo and much more expensive.

Answer (score -1):

Working example:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36446285/7457316)

is that the required effect?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  No , the required effect is a row with much more height and there is Listbox Not ComboBox